# Loading css background images dynamically for slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-experience

I have a slider implemented for latest movies coming in. The images are loaded from css background image property. Is there any way to call this background images dynamically into the slider only using css background property

Comment: can you please show your code?,so that i can try to help....

Comment: You can do so "only using css background property" but for doing so dynamically you'll need some scripting language like js.

Answer (score 0):

You cant just Css background property. You need to call some jquery/javascript.

In Javascript you can for() like this;

```
 var array = ["#000000","#cc0000","#444444"];

 for ( var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
      $('.sampleDiv').css('background',''+array[i]+'');
 }
```

its just a idea,

And Maybe you can call array with javascript setInterval();

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/kMWdW/1/)